# Checkin error on subversion server installed on AWS EC2

Tags: apache, svn, amazon-ec2, tortoisesvn, httpd.conf

I installed subversion server on AWS EC2. Most of it works fine. I'm able to checkout but unable to checkin file on command line. I get svn: E000013: could not begin a transaction. Error in the logs are:

```
[Wed Jan 20 22:02:25.679636 2016] [:error] [pid 28816] [client 96.242.58.29:53390] Can't open file '/var/www/svn/repos/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied  [500, #13]
```

This is my syntax for subversion.conf

```
cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf 
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

  <Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
     SVNListParentPath on
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Subversion Repositories"
     AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
     Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

Repo permissions look like this:

```
ls -lrt /var/www/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root   root    6 Sep 17 09:07 cgi-bin
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root   root   28 Jan 20 20:17 html
drwsrwsr-x. 3 apache apache 18 Jan 20 20:25 svn

ls -lrt /var/www/svn
total 0
drwsr-sr-x. 6 apache apache 80 Jan 20 20:25 repos

httpd ps -ef is:

 ps -ef | grep httpd
 root     28809     1  0 21:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
 apache   28811 28809  0 21:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
 apache   28813 28809  0 21:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
 apache   28814 28809  0 21:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
 apache   28815 28809  0 21:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
 apache   28816 28809  0 21:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
 apache   28817 28809  0 21:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
 apache   28818 28809  0 22:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
 apache   28819 28809  0 22:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
 ec2-user 28856  9252  0 22:07 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved from this post. SELinux issue. Used the 2 option from this post:

https://serverfault.com/questions/625579/svn-cant-open-file-var-www-svn-repo-db-txn-current-lock-permission-denied